# how to use videoJS and videoJS playlist and videoJS playlist ui with webpack

Tags: javascript, symfony, webpack, video.js, webpack-encore

i have project using symfony, i'm using encoreJS for front end.
actually i make a player for list of videos and it's work fine.
but i want to use videojs-playlist-ui to make this [example](http://videojs.com/advanced/)

but when i use videojs-playlist-ui with webpack

```
import videojs from 'video.js';
require('videojs-playlist');
require('videojs-playlist-ui');
```

and after create player and it's work then make `player.playlistUi();` after this player not work and see this erorr

> Uncaught TypeError: player.playlistUi is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

same problem

Here's my solution. Just manually register the playlist-ui plugin.

```
import videojs from 'video.js'
const playlistUi = require('videojs-playlist-ui');

videojs.registerPlugin('playlistUi', playlistUi.default);
```